# I am trying to execute this facebook api but it is not working....can you suggest any corrections

Tags: javascript, web-deployment

```
function getalbum(){
    FB.api(
        '/me',
        'GET',
        {"fields":"albums{name,link}"},
        function(response) {
            var album=response.data[1]
            document.getElementById("photo").innerHTML=album.link;
        }
  )};
```

Whenever I am trying to print the album link it shows error `cannot read the property '1' of unknown`

Comment: Block quotes are for quoting text, not formatting code. Please use the **{}** toolbar button, Ctrl+K, or four-space indentation to format code in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the [facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api):

So your code should be:

```
function getalbum(){
   FB.api(
       '/me',
       'GET',
       {"fields":"albums{name,link}"},
       function(response) {
           if (response.error) {
              console.log(error);
           } else {
              if (response.albums.length > 0) {
                  var album=response.albums[0]
                  document.getElementById("photo").innerHTML=album.link;
              }
           }
       }
)};
```

Note that your `albums` property is directly accessible on the `response` object.

You need to use the `data` of the response object only when the results are paginated, as explained in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#paging)

Comment: It is still showing that cannot read property length of undefined.even after removing length the same problem arrives

Comment: Did you try to console.log(response) ? You might find interesting informations...